# Non Initialized Pointers in QT

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

In QT I follow the way of writing the interface in a header file, then the implementation in .cpp files. In my case I have One MainApplication and Two Dialogs as children of the MainApplication

so in the MainApplication Header , two un-initialized Pointers to the two Dialogs

```
 MemberForm *memberForm;
AboutForm *aboutUsForm;
```

As Far as I know that the pointer will be Null and this following conditions evaluates to true

```
memberForm == NULL //False
aboutUsForm == NULL //False
```

As Far as I know that all non-initialized pointers are NULL pointers,so this is weird for me. what makes it more weird that removing one of the pointers in the header, the conditions evaluates true

```
 MemberForm *memberForm;
//AboutForm *aboutUsForm; // Removing the pointer
```

The Condition evaluates true

```
memberForm == NULL //True
```

I appreciate any response.
PS: If u are gonna to downvote the post please leave comment explaining why ..

Comment: Your second test is just "luck", those members won't be initialized, you need to do that yourself.

Comment: In C++, pointers are not initialized to NULL/nullptr without explicit assignment. The default value is undefined and will point to uninitialized memory in most cases. In some setups, like debug builds with MSVC, the compiler *might* happen to decide to initialize the values with null, but that's nothing you can rely on at all - it will already break in release builds.

Comment: @Mat  yes I am a lucky boy :D
and It looks out that I have to study more ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw ("naked") pointer members of heap-allocated objects are not initialized in either C nor C++. Their value is undefined and can not be depended on before the first initialization. Whatever value you've got, you got it by coincidence, not by design.

Generally, raw pointers to objects allocated on the heap in C++ are a sure-fire way of shooting yourself in the foot, and are often a sign of bad design. There is really no point in dragging the unsafe aspects of C into C++. You've got C++'s power, use it to help yourself.

A smart pointer, like `QScopedPointer`, has saner behavior and you should use it instead.

1. You can check if it was initialized.
2. You don't need to worry about deleting the pointed-to-value. It will be deleted automatically when the smart pointer is destructed - at the time the compiler-generated destructor code runs for that class that carries the smart pointer.